# How to create array of object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

My Class look like this:

```
var Coin = {
    _id: null,
    createGame: function(id) {
     this._id = id;
    },
    start: function() {

    }
};
```

I'm trying to create an array of objects, but I can create only one.
Could someone tell what i'm doing wrong?

I create array like this:

```
CoinArray = [];
CoinArray['123'] = new Coin.createGame(123);
CoinArray['333'] = new Coin.createGame(333);
CoinArray['333'].start
```

At the end I want to have array with object and for example I will take first el of array, and execute other method from Coin class.

Comment: What are you expecting `CoinArray` to look like after creating the array like that? That'll help us figure out how to help.

Comment: Do you really want an **array** or do you actually want an `id -> coin` map?

Comment: if the below resolved your issue should accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to push a newly created item to your array like below:

```
CoinArray.push(new Coin.Create('123));
```

On the other hand if you want to create an object with keys ids and values corresponding Coin objects, you should try this:

```
CoinDictionary = {};
CoinDictionary['123'] = new Coin.Create('123');
```

**Note**:

I think that you should refactor a bit the `Coin` if you want to use it as a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

```
function Coin(id){
    this.id = id;
}
```

Doing this change you can use it as below:

```
CoinArray.push(new Coin('123'));
```

```js
function Coin(id){
    this.id = id;
}

var CoinArray = [];
CoinArray.push(new Coin('123'));
CoinArray.push(new Coin('456'));
CoinArray.push(new Coin('789'));

console.log(CoinArray);
```

**Update**

> At the end I want to have array with object and for example I will
>   take first el of array, and execute other method from Coin class.

For this purpose If I were you I would have gone with the creation of an object with keys the ids and values references to `Coin` objects:

```js
function Coin(id){
    this.id = id;
}

Coin.prototype.start = function(){
    console.log("game with id "+this.id+" started.");
}

Coins = {}
Coins['123'] = new Coin('123');
Coins['456'] = new Coin('456');
Coins['789'] = new Coin('789');

Coins['456'].start();
```

Comment: result look like this -> { '123': createGame {} } in my opinion its not correct

Comment: @user3458952: *"in my opinion its not correct"* That really depends on what you want/need. There is no absolute right and wrong, only what is and what isn't appropriate for your use case. E.g. if you want to be able to access `Coin`s by IDs then using an array is less convenient.

Comment: @user3458952 Please check the snippet I added and let me know if that what you expect. If so, then you have to follow the Note section, since I don't see how this could be done through `new Coin.Create(...)`. I don't see any `Create` method there.

Comment: please check now

Comment: My structure of code is wrong? I read somewhere that is emc5 standard. Questions is why I can;t create a few object.?

Comment: @user3458952 I am sorry but I don't get what you mean. What is ECMA5 standard? Where it is mentioned that you can't create a few objects?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Coin {
  constructor(id) {
    this._id = id;
  }
  start() {
    console.log('starting');
  }
}

CoinArray = [];
CoinArray['123'] = new Coin(123);
CoinArray['333'] = new Coin(333);
CoinArray['123'].start();
```

Also i would suggest managing id's that way:

```
let id = 0;
class Coin {
  constructor() {
    this._id = id++;
  }
  start() {
    console.log('starting');
  }
}

CoinArray = [];
CoinArray.push(new Coin());
CoinArray.push(new Coin());
CoinArray[0].start();
```

Comment: My structure of code is wrong? I read somewhere that is emc5 standard. Questions is why I can;t create a few object.?

Comment: @user3458952 ES6 was standardized 2 years ago, in 2015. Your structure is not wrong, but it is not widely used anymore.

Comment: @user3458952 no, you should declare a function and then create objects with new if you want, but classes are just better nowadays.